# Date pipe is Working fine in Html Interpolation but not Working in Mat-DatePicker Input Fields

Tags: angular5, angular6, angular7

I want to display a date in dd/MM/YYYY format when a user pick the date using the mat Datepicker but when i use the Datepipe in Datepicker it not shows any Date when we pick

```
   <mat-form-field class="box">
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Generate Date" maxlength="10px" [readonly]="isNew1"
      [ngModel]="quotation?.generateDate | date: 'dd/MM/yy'"
      (ngModelChange)="quotation.generateDate=$event" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker [disabled]="isNew1" #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have imported DatePipe in your .ts

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private date: DatePipe)
```

**Note:** If you have an error of static injection Datepipe then please import DatePipe in your module.ts file

If this is not fixing your issue then you can make function on date selection that transform your date to your preferred format just like below:

```
<mat-form-field class="box">
   <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" 
      placeholder="Generate Date"
      maxlength="10px"
      [readonly]="isNew1"
      [ngModel]="quotation?.generateDate"
      (ngModelChange)="onDateSelection(quotation?.generateDate)"
      [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
   >
   <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   <mat-datepicker [disabled]="isNew1" #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Now in your .ts file:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

export class XComponent{

    constructor(private date: DatePipe)

    onDateSelection(date: Date): string {
        return this.date.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    }

}
```

Here are the available angular date pipe formats: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe