# How to convert date format in get api of all object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new in angular, I am getting object through api

```
    data= [
  {
    "Id": 4,    
    "IssueDate": "2021-01-25T15:17:00.85",
    "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-25T15:25:40.263",
  },
  {
    "Id": 5,
    "IssueDate": "2021-01-25T15:25:40.263",
    "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-25T15:25:40.263"
  }
]
```

In this I am getting IssueDate and ExpiryDate I am getting in different format, I want to change it into `DD-MM-YYYY` so is there any way to change the format of both?

Comment: You can use DatePipe. This answer can help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53928624/date-pipe-is-working-fine-in-html-interpolation-but-not-working-in-mat-datepicke/53930244#53930244

Comment: Angular DatePipe: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use date pipe if you want to show them on UI. Otherwise use

```
this.data = this.data.map(d => ({ ...d, IssueDate: new Date(d.IssueDate), ExpiryDate: new Date(d.ExpiryDate) }))
```

Comment: No, I want to change it in TS file

Comment: As you said I used this in html like this: <td>{{ head.dataType ==='dropDown' ? tableData[head.mappedName]: head.dataType ==='date' ? tableData[head.mappedName] | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy' : tableData[head.mappedProperty] }}</td>

Comment: But getting error: Parser Error: Conditional expression head.dataType ==='date' ? tableData[head.mappedName] | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy' : tableData[head.mappedProperty] requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression [{{ head.dataType ==='dropDown' ? tableData[head.mappedName]: head.dataType ==='date' ? tableData[head.mappedName] | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy' : tableData[head.mappedProperty] }}] i

Comment: just add parenthesis around (tableData[head.mappedName] | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy')

Comment: for showing purpose its correct, but when I am patching this date to my datepicker, it showing me invalid date

Comment: because in ts file it is not in expected format

Comment: try this.data = this.data.map(d => ({ ...d, IssueDate: new Date(d.IssueDate), ExpiryDate: new Date(d.ExpiryDate) }))

Comment: which date picker are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227875/discussion-between-zainhassan-and-techguy).

Comment: it showing me like this Mon Jan 25 2021 15:17:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the following in ts file with your response.

```js
const data= [
  {
    "Id": 4,    
    "IssueDate": "2021-01-25T15:17:00.85",
    "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-25T15:25:40.263",
  },
  {
    "Id": 5,
    "IssueDate": "2021-01-25T15:25:40.263",
    "ExpiryDate": "2021-01-25T15:25:40.263"
  }
];

data.map((each_data) => {
   const issue_date = new Date(each_data.IssueDate);
   const exp_date = new Date(each_data.ExpiryDate);
   each_data.IssueDate = `${issue_date.getDate()}-${issue_date.getMonth()+1}-${issue_date.getFullYear()}`
   each_data.ExpiryDate = `${exp_date.getDate()}-${exp_date.getMonth()+1}-${exp_date.getFullYear()}`
  
});

console.log(data);
```